# Unable to catch Arithmetic exception (Catching IllegalArgumentException fine though)

Tags: java, exception, junit

Please have a look at mine constructor below, I'm creating a Fraction from a String:

```
public Fraction(String str)
    {
        if(str.isEmpty())
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The str (String) parameter cannot be empty!");
        }
             int[] fractionData= new int[2];
             String[] data = str.split("/");
             try
             {
                 if(data.length==0)
                 throw new IllegalArgumentException("The str (String) parameter cannot be empty");
             }
             catch (IllegalArgumentException ex)
             {
                 System.out.println(ex.toString());
             }
             try
             {
                fractionData[0] = Integer.parseInt(data[0]); 
             }
             catch (IllegalArgumentException ex)
             {
                 System.out.println(ex.toString());
             }

             try
             {
                 fractionData[1] = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
                 if(fractionData[1]==0) throw new ArithmeticException("Denominator can't be 0");
             }
             catch (ArithmeticException ex)
             {
                 System.out.println(ex.toString());
             }
             fractionData = normalize(fractionData[0],fractionData[1]);
             this.numerator = fractionData[0];
             this.denominator = fractionData[1];
    }
```

I'm catching the IllegalArgumentException fine, but fail to catch the ArithemticException. I can test both successfully

```
@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testIllegalArgumenException() throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        Fraction g =  new Fraction("");
    }
    @Test(expected=ArithmeticException.class)
    public void testArithmeticException() throws ArithmeticException
    {
        Fraction g = new Fraction(1/0);
    }
```

Thanks the comments from @xp500 I've changed my code to:

```
public Fraction(String str)
    {
        if(str.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The str (String) parameter cannot be empty!");
             int[] fractionData= new int[2];
             String[] data = str.split("/");
             if (data.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) throw new NumberFormatException("only numbers allowed in the string");
             fractionData[0] = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
             fractionData[1] = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
             if(fractionData[1]==0) throw new ArithmeticException("Denominator can't be 0"); 
             fractionData = normalize(fractionData[0],fractionData[1]);
             this.numerator = fractionData[0];
             this.denominator = fractionData[1];
    }
```

It doesn't quote "only numbers allowed in the string", but stops initializing the Fraction as 0/0 in case String with letters is used to initialize the Fraction and throws the other exceptions with quoted text. The lesson for me is: DON'T CATCH EXCEPTIONS UNLESS YOU'RE ACTUALLY DOING SOMETHING WITH THEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of comments about the code.

Your usage of the exceptions is making the code unreadable and hard to follow. You should try to use less try catch blocks. I think it would be better if you wrote something along the lines of

```
if (data.length==0) {
   System.out.println(ex.toString());
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("The str (String) parameter cannot be empty");
}
```

and not catch that exception, since you want to tell the caller that an exception occured.

Also, `fractionData[0] = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);` throws a NumberFormatException, not IllegalArgumentException

The ArithmeticException isn't being thrown since you are catching it inside the constructor, and not rethrowing it. Please note that, after catching it, your fraction will be initialized in an invalid state, since

```
fractionData = normalize(fractionData[0],fractionData[1]);
this.numerator = fractionData[0];
this.denominator = fractionData[1];
```

will be executed. Again, you might want to rewrite those lines for something like

```
if(fractionData[1]==0) {
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
    throw new ArithmeticException("Denominator can't be 0");
}
```

You don't need to write throws Exception, in your test methods, since you are expecting an exception to be thrown, the method itself won't throw that exception.

I hope that helps!

Comment: xp500 and Antoniossss,thanks for getting back to me.True,my code is littered with unnecessary try&catch.I thought it's required if you want the console to print your text to the exception,but it isn't: if(str.isEmpty())
  {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("The str (String) parameter cannot be empty!");
  } still throws IllegalArgumentException: The str (String) parameter cannot be empty! without catch block.

Comment: Although I still don't understand why: try
    {
     fractionData[0] = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
     throw new NumberFormatException("only numbers allowed in the string");
    }
   
    catch (NumberFormatException ex)
    {
     System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
    try
    {
    if(fractionData[1]==0) throw new ArithmeticException("Denominator can't be 0"); 
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException ex)
    {
     System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }  throws: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "st"
java.lang.ArithmeticException: Denominator can't be 0 SEENEXT COMMENT

Comment: When public static void main(String[] args) {StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder ("st"); 
String stri = str.toString();
Fraction g =  new Fraction(stri);
System.out.println(g.toString()); Why it is printing the 'Denominator can't be 0' but not 'only numbers allowed in the string' ?

Comment: What I mean is, I'm attaching the text to both ArithmeticException and NumberFormatException but only the 'Denominator can't be 0' is printed. By the way, the Fraction is being created in 0/0 format, which is not what I want.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, that's because I'm catching the exception in Try&Catch block?

Comment: @user3274207 Catching an Exception means that you will somehow handle the error, and so the caller will not know about the Exception being thrown. If you want to handle it, and also notify the caller, you should rethrow the exception from the catch block (i.e. throw e). Also, if you throw an Exception and don't catch it, then the code of that function will stop executing there.

Comment: @user3274207 I was just reading your new code. That looks waaay better! Good job. What I meant by the NumberFormatException, is that Integer.parseInt() already throws that exception, no need for you to manually check (which, by the way, you are only checking for letters, so if I give you "!!--" you won't notice it!). What you could do is surround the parseInt calls with a try catch, catch that Exception and rethrow it with your custom message.

Comment: @user3274207 And finally, yes, the Fraction was being created with 0/0 because you caught the Exception, but don't forget that the code outside the try block will still execute!  So you were basically knowing about the error, and not doing anything. I assume that in your new code, it should work as expected.

Comment: @user3274207 And I read about what you were saying about it not saying that "Only numbers are allowed". That is because you are calling toString() on data, where data is the array you created from split. So it will try to see if data.toString().matches(letters). But data is probably something like "[...]", so it doesn't match that regex. Try what I told you some comments above!

Answer (score 2):

Yo are catching `ArithmeticException` but you are not retrowing it(like other exceptions)